# determinant of a matrix 37x37

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, matrix

I have done a program to calculate a determinant of a matrix. My program works, but the problem is that it takes long time to calculate, especially for big matrix. Could you tell me how can a perform my program in order to calculate the determinant in the shortest possible time?

```
    double Matrice::Determinant(int n)
{
   cout<<"n = "<<n<<endl;
   int i,j,j1,j2;
   double det = 0;
   Matrice tmp(n,n);
   if (n < 1) 
   {
   } 
   else if (n == 1) 
   { 
      det = this->get_el(0,0);
   } else if (n == 2) {
      det = this->get_el(0,0) * this->get_el(1,1) - this->get_el(1,0) * this->get_el(0,1);
   } else {
      det = 0;
      for (j1=0;j1<n;j1++) {
         for (i=1;i<n;i++) {
            j2 = 0;
            for (j=0;j<n;j++) {
               if (j == j1)
                  continue;
               tmp.set_el(i-1,j2,get_el(i,j));
               j2++;
            }
         }
         det += pow(-1.0,1.0+j1+1.0) * get_el(0,j1) * tmp.Determinant(n-1);
      }
   }
   return det;
}
```

Comment: A problem like this may better be solved by [Math.StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/). They're good at optimized algorithms, especially for a math heavy problem like this.

Comment: From a C++-POV, the biggest loss in performance is caused by your temporary matrix `tmp`, and the way you iterate through each element to initialize it.

Comment: Ok, i will post it there. thank you.

Comment: There are numeric methods to approximate the determinant of a matrix and perform much, much faster. but as said before, math.stackexchange will be your best bet for those

Comment: Your current algorithm appears at first glance to be `O(n^3)`, but then there's that recursive call in there and I see it's really `O(n^n)` or something like that. You can do it in `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Convert your matrix to diagonal form (Gauss method) and multiply the diagonal elements.

Comment: Of course your program works, you copied the code from http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/determinant/ (with some small changes). I would try LU decomposition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm, which looks like a straight-forward implementation of the definition formula, is in `O(n!)`.

A standard algorithm in `O(n^3)` consists in first transforming it into a triangular matrix using [Gauss elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). Once you have done this, the determinant is the product of the diagonal elements.