# How do I calculate the determinant of a 6x6 matrix in C++ really fast?

Tags: c++, performance

In C++ I need to calculate the determinant of a 6x6 matrix really fast.

This is how I would do this for a 2x2 matrix:

```
double det2(double A[2][2]) {
   return A[0][0]*A[1][1] - A[0][1]*A[1][0];
}
```

I want a similar function for the determinant of a 6x6 matrix but I do not want to write it by hand since it contains 6! = 720 terms where each term is the product of 6 elements in the matrix.

Therefore I want to use Leibniz formula:

```
static int perms6[720][6];
static int signs6[720];
double det6(double A[6][6]) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 720; i++) {
     int j0 = perms6[i][0];
     int j1 = perms6[i][1];
     int j2 = perms6[i][2];
     int j3 = perms6[i][3];
     int j4 = perms6[i][4];
     int j5 = perms6[i][5];
     sum += signs6[i]*A[0]*A[j0]*A[1]*A[j1]*A[2]*A[j2]*A[3]*A[j3]*A[4]*A[j4]*A[5]*A[j5];
  }
  return sum; 
}
```

**How do I find the permutations and the signs?**

Is there some way I could get the compiler to do more of the work (e.g. C macros or template metaprogramming) so that the function would be even faster?

EDIT:
I just timed the following code (Eigen):

```
Matrix<double,6,6>  A;
// ... fill A

for(long i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    PartialPivLU< Matrix<double,6,6> > LU(A);
    double d = LU.determinant();
}
```

to 1.25 s. So using LU or Gauss decomposition is definitely fast enough for my use!

Comment: The determinant is not needed very often, are you sure you have to calculate it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [determinant of a matrix 37x37](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674580/determinant-of-a-matrix-37x37)

Comment: Given that you're dealing with a fixed size, that method could be applied symbolically, to give a matrix of (hopefully) simple formulae for each item in the determinant. In principle, this symbolic evaluation and simplification could be done by C++ template metaprogramming. It's not really designed for the job, though, plus you only need one symbolic answer anyway. Why not evaluate that using a tool designed for symbolic math, then use that result for normal C++ code, dropping the metaprogramming entirely?

Comment: Yes If I had Mathematica I could get it to calculate the expression symbolically and then use its function for converting to C code. I tried Wolfram Alpha but it bails out at 5x5. I could use Laplace's formula to construct the 6x6 solution from 6 5x5 solutions but this is cumbersome. Also the plain text output of Wolfram Alpha is bad. I would have to write a python script to convert spaces to multiplication signs etc.

Comment: Inspired by your post I got a new idea: write a script in Python that uses Leibniz formula to spew out C code for the determinant of a NxN matrix for any N.

Comment: I believe your edit should be an (accepted) answer or comment to rubenvb's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), An example can be found [here](http://www.coin-or.org/CppAD/Doc/eigen_det.cpp.xml).

Comment: Eigen is great but I think your example is outdated. I think the best way in Eigen would be to construct a Eigen::PartialPivLU object and then call the determinant() function on this. Still I think an explicit 720 term function would be faster.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Gauss method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Computing_determinants) to make the matrix upper-triangular. For every operation you know how determinant is changed (not changed of multiplied by constant `d`) and it works in `O(n^3)`. After that just multiply numbers on main diagonal and delete to product of all `d`'s

Comment: I think doing a LU decomposition would be faster. This is recommended by Numerical Recepies. Still I think an explicit formula will be faster than any decomposition?

Comment: @Andy Not if you expanded formula takes more operations to compute, than a decomposition. And LU decomposition is the same as Gauss pivoting, it's just useful to solve same system with many different right hand sides.